# How can I search from quick box and view the result page in Java for cucumber with selenium testing

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm

```
@When("^I click on search space.$")
    public void I_click_on_search_space() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("srch")).click();
    }

    @When("^I type on search space.$")
    public void I_type_on_search_space() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys("Publications");
    }

    @When("^click on search button.$")
    public void click_on_search_button() throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("srch")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
    }

    @When("^I will recieve available information on my search.$")
    public void I_will_recieve_available_information_on_my_search() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.name("option")).isDisplayed();   
    }

    @Then("^I will be on Search page.$")
    public void I_will_be_on_Search_page() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Search"));   
    }
```

this is the code so far. It works the enter also. But the page does not loaded. So can I know why it is? How can I fix that problem.

The scenario is also passed. But the resulted page does not display.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I did not receive my requested page from search box because I click on the search box. I Press enter key on search box. But my my enter key should on 'Publication.'

The below is the working code.

```
@When("^I click on search space.$")
    public void I_click_on_search_space() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("srch")).click();
    }

    @When("^I type on search space.$")
    public void I_type_on_search_space() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys("Publications");
    }

    @When("^click on search button.$")
    public void click_on_search_button() throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
    }

    @When("^I will recieve available information on my search.$")
    public void I_will_recieve_available_information_on_my_search() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.name("option")).isDisplayed();   
    }

    @Then("^I will be on Search page.$")
    public void I_will_be_on_Search_page() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Search"));   
    }
```